# Print a letter before each row without using <ol> or a compiled array

Tags: php

Witch is the best way to print a letter (beginning from A) before each row of a list without using html ordered list `<ol><li></li>...</ol>` and without using an array that contain the alphabet?

```
es:
A. first row
B. second row
C. third row
```

thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: It stills gives you an array, but did you try using range? Like so: `range('a', 'z')`

Comment: could use chr(65) to get A and add +1 each time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this, using `++` on a variable containing a letter...

```
$letter = 'A';
foreach ($list as $item) {
    echo $letter++, '. ', $item, "\n";
}
```

See [the increment operator's manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) for more information on this behaviour.  Essentially, calling `++` on a one-character string, where that character is an `A-Za-z` letter, will make the string into the next letter.

Comment: this is a much better answer. I actually never knew you could just increment alpha characters... what happens on multibyte charsets?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a string and substr it on every iteration:

```
<?php

$alph = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

$rows = array(); //whatever your rows are that you're printing

$i = 0;
foreach($rows AS $r): ?>

<?php echo substr($alph, $i, 1); ?> x row<br>

<?php $i ++; endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
<?php
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) 
{
    echo chr(65+$i) . '. ' . $1;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$l = 'a';
foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo strtoupper($l).". {$row}\n";
    $l++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon how long your list is, you can get away with this:

```
$start = 'A';
foreach ($lists as $li) {
   echo "$start. $li\n";
   $start++;
}
```

If you don't even want to specify the start, you can use the ascii codes too.

```
foreach ($lists as $num => $li) {
   echo chr($num + 65) . ". $li\n";
}
```